# Is it possible to manually change the base type of a custom module?

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to know if it is possible to change the base type from which a custom module extends. In my case I have a module called Action that extends from Basic. Now this module is required to accept file uploads, so I need to extend from the File base module.

In the peronsalized module Action I have changed the type manually, when repairing a series of fields related to the File type are created, but the  field that allows me to upload the file is not created.

I appreciate your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Disclaimer: I only know SugarCRM, not SuiteCRM.*</sup>

It should be possible to change the base type by doing these two things:

1. Go to `modules/<module name>/vardefs.php` and look for either 
   `VardefManager::createVardef(`
   or
   `'uses' => array(`.
   One of these contains `'basic'`.
   Replace it with `'file'`.
2. Make sure to add any new fields that are inherited from that base type as properties in the bean's class file, usually named something like `modules/<module>/<module>[_sugar].php`

Based on `include/SugarObjects/templates/file/vardefs.php` those fields should be added (however in SuiteCRM this fields may differ) to the class:

```
public $document_name;
public $name;
public $filename;
public $file_ext;
public $file_mime_type;
public $uploadfile;
public $active_date;
public $exp_date;
public $category_id;
public $subcategory_id;
public $status_id;
public $status;
```